# What is the output of FIT() in KNeighborsClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

For OLS, I can extract the coefficients on train and apply them on test data to get y_hat.
For KNN, I thought we pick K observation close to a test observation to make the decision on label and therefore there is no need to fit within the train data.
So what is the role of knn.fit(train_data, train_labels) and what does it produce?
Can anyone please help enlightening me?
HHC

```
# Create and fit a nearest-neighbor classifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(train_data, train_labels) 

predicted = knn.predict(test_data)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65469094/what-happens-when-we-apply-fit-method-to-a-knn-model-in-scikit-learn-if-knn-h

Answer (score 0):

`knn.fit(train_data, train_labels)` memorizes the training data. It calculates the distances between all data points in the training dataset (train_data) to find the nearest neighbors for each data point. Then it associates each data point in the training dataset with its corresponding label or class from the `train_labels` dataset. Essentially, it stores these associations in memory. During prediction, it uses this stored information to make predictions.

`knn.fit()` modifies the `knn` object in place and returns the modified `knn` object. those properties will change

```
knn.classes_
knn.n_samples_fit_
knn.effective_metric_
```

if you print those before `knn.fit`, your compiler will throw error. To see which properties changes, call `dir(knn)` before `knn.fit` and after